# Conditional statement in V-Model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I have a dynamic form which contains a list of elements specified in the following way:

```
element1: { name: "property1", value: "value1", defaultValue: "defaultvalue1", usingDefaultValue: true, type: "String/Enum/Int/Long }
```

This list of elements is constantly published via a WebSocket and stored in a Vuex store. Each element corresponds to an input, which displays either the `value` or the `defaultValue`, depending on a toggle switch. These values are bound to the input fields using `v-model`.

I use the `vuex-map-fields` library to help with the dynamic multi row fields. They are defined as follows:

```
  computed: {
     ...mapMultiRowFields(`elementsStore`, ["elements"])
  },
```

The fields are passed into a list component using a `v-for`:

```
  <v-layout v-for="element in elements" :key="element.name">
    <element-list-item :element="element"></element-list-item>
  </v-layout>
```

Now, **the following works perfectly as I expect**:

```
<v-text-field
    v-model="element.useDefaultValue ? element.defaultValue : element.value"
</v-text-field>
```

However, whenever I use `npm run lint`, I get the following error message:

```
error: 'v-model' directives require the attribute value which is valid as LHS (vue/valid-v-model)
```

**Is there a better way to achieve this same behaviour?**

I'm going to assume the error message is there for a good reason.

One alternative approach I have tried is using a computed property. However, this did not work and immediately displayed errors in the console.

Comment: By "as I expect" do you mean that when the user edits the text field, they are changing the default value and not the value? That seems like an odd use case.

Comment: @StephenThomas I should have been more clear on this. The `mapMultiRowFields` binds the form input to the Vuex store by adding a getter and a setter. This is done for each element/input field. When the user modifies the input value, the store value is changed. However, when the store value is changed (i.e., a WebSocket message), the input value is updated. I effectively "pause" the WebSocket updates while a user is modifying a field, and resume after the form is submitted/saved.